# React-hook-form, передача ref-a, в качестве props-а, компоненту Input

Tags: reactjs

Недавно начал изучать react-hook-form и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Предположим имеется отдельный компонент <Input tag='input' type='text' name='name'...../>, который возвращает input/select/checkbox в зависимости от переданных props-ов. При использовании react-hook-form обязательным является использование ref-а, но как его передать в качестве props-a? И вообще, возможен ли такой механизм или при использовании react-hook-form не предусмотрено создание input-ов с помощью отдельного компонента?

```
import React from 'react'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import {Button} from '../../components'
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form'

function Order() {
    const {register, handleSubmit, errors} = useForm()

    const submitForm = (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                {/* <input 
                        type="text"
                        name='name' 
                        placeholder='Ім`я' 
                        className={`input input__solid input__light ${errors.name ? 'input__error' : ''}`} 
                        ref={register({required: true})}
                /> */}
                    
                <Input tag="input" type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name' ref={register({required: true})} className={`${errors.name ? 'input__error' : ''}`}  solid light/>

                <Button onClick={handleSubmit(submitForm)} type="submit" solid light>Press</Button>
            </form>
       </div>
    )
}

function Input({tag, type, placeholder, name, className, ref, solid, dark, light}) {
    let outputInput = null

    if(tag === 'input'){
        outputInput = <input type={type} name={name} placeholder={placeholder} ref={ref} className={classNames('input', className, {
            'input--dark': dark,
            'input--light': light,
            'input__solid': solid,
        })}/>
    }
    // else if...

    return (
        outputInput
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да передать `ref` возможно, ниже привожу работающий пример. А вообще данную задачу с `react-hook-form` можно решить больше чем двумя способами.

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const Order = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const submitForm = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
      <Input
        tag="input"
        type="text"
        name="name"
        placeholder="Name"
        defaultValue=""
        ref={register({ required: false })}
      />
      <Input
        tag="checkbox"
        type="checkbox"
        name="checkbox"
        ref={register({ required: false })}
        label="Label for checkbox"
      />
      <button type="submit">Press</button>
    </form>
  );
};

const Input = React.forwardRef(
  ({ tag, name, label, ...restProps }, forwardedRef) => {
    switch (tag) {
      case "input":
        return <input name={name} ref={forwardedRef} {...restProps} />;
      case "checkbox":
        return (
          <div>
            <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
            <input name={name} ref={forwardedRef} {...restProps} />
          </div>
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
);

export default Order;
```